# The computation of an inverse limit of modules.

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

I am trying to read the book [**Euler System** by *Karl Rubin.*](http://swc.math.arizona.edu/aws/1999/99RubinES.pdf) But I found something confusing, right at the page $1,$ or the page $9$ in the book. There we find that:

> Let $\mathcal O$ be the ring of integers of a finite extension $\Phi$ of $\mathbb Q_p,$ where $p$ is a rational prime, let $G_K=\text{Gal}(\bar K,K),$ where $K$ is a field, and let $T$ be a free $\mathcal O-$module of finite rank with a continuous action of $G_K.$ Then we define $V=T\otimes_\mathcal O \Phi, W=V/T=T\otimes_\mathcal O(\Phi/\mathcal O),$ and $W_M=M^{-1}T/T\subset W$ for non-zero $M\in\mathcal O.$
>   Then $$T=\varprojlim W_M.$$

I cannot understand the last equation: How shall we make these $W_M$ into an inverse system, by which maps? The only relation that came into my mind is the division: if $M\mid N,$ then $\exists \rho_{N,M}:W_N\rightarrow W_M,$ satisfying the two defining conditions. I don't see how this done.
I think that, if I know about the system in question, I can compute the limit directly, or projectively, thus I ask for only the system. :)
Thanks for any hints in advance.

P.S. The above paragragh is not from the book, but aapted from the book, which does not change the question, I surmise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The map $\rho_{N, M}$ is just multiplication by $N/M$, which takes $N^{-1} T$ surjectively to $M^{-1}T$ and which is well-defined mod $T$. It is easier if you only consider $M, N$ to be powers of a chosen uniformizer of $\Phi$ (you will compute the same limit, but with less of a hassle).

You might want to learn about the Tate module of an elliptic curve before reading that book, then every time you see $T, V, W$ just think of that example (here $\Phi = \mathbb{Q}_p$).

(It is also helpful to consider the one-dimensional free module $T$.)

Comment: Thanks for your inspiring answer: the uniformizer is indeed one great tool that I shall have thought of. :)

Answer (score 1):

I think that the fundamental lemma is the following:

Let $A$ be an integral ring with fractional field $K$. For $x \neq 0$, denote by $A_x$ the localized ring of $A$ at $x$. if $x | y$, we have an inclusion $A_x \hookrightarrow A_y$, by sending $\frac{1}{x}$ to $\frac{y}{x} \frac{1}{y}$ and for any $x$ we have inclusion $A_x \hookrightarrow K$; and all these inclusions are compatible. Prove that this gives an isomorphism $\varinjlim A_x \cong K$ (I think that the limit is an injective one).

Your particular problem is of the same flavour.

Edit : In fact, we want $A$ and not $K$. So you have to prove the following equality: $\varprojlim A_x \cong A$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It is intriguing! :D

Comment: It is $\varprojlim$ in the cited text. Hm ...

Comment: But I think that the principle is similar. :)